# ElasticSearch aggregation on a modified term

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'd like to perform an aggregation grouping by a modified version of a message *message* field.

I have lots of messages like

invalid x with uuid=1e659cfc-a375-4a8a-88f5-467419fdf87d
invalid x with uuid=49c4742e-0368-49a2-aab4-7f59b2e89ec8

I want them to end up in the same aggregation bucket by replacing the uuid with ''
the idea would be something in the direction of:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    query": {
    }
    "aggs": {
        "my_aggregation": {
            "terms": {
                "size": 1000,
                "field": "message.keyword.replace(uuid_regex,'<UUID>')"
            }
        }
    }
}
```